# Как найти папку в ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, терминал

Получил легаси проект, в котором не особо следили за соглашениями об именовании и расположении папок.
Могу только предполагать как должны называться папки и файлы.

Отсюда вопросы:
1) Как найти папку по имени?
Например, `find workers -type d` не особо помогает. Ищет только в текущем каталоге, а нужно по всей системе.

2) Как найти файл по части имени?
Т.е. часть имени должна быть `_workers.rb`, по ней нужно осуществить поиск

Поиск по всей системе.

Comment: `find / -type d -iname '*часть имени*'` (звёздочки и кавычки не стирать)

Comment: ну как так? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find

Comment: @diproart а теперь есть легальная отмазка: РКН меня забанил в вики!

Comment: @andreymal, неплохо бы добавить `-xdev`.

Comment: Если есть база данных, по состоянию на последнее её обновление можно запустить команду `locate`. Это во много раз быстрее, чем `find`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**1) Как найти папку по имени?**

`find / -type d -name 'workers'`

`/` - искать по всей системе, то есть начинать с точки монтирования "/"

`-type d` - искать только папки

`-name 'workers'` - в данном случае точное совпадение с workers

**2) Как найти файл по части имени?**

`find / -type f -name '*_workers.rb'`

`/` - искать по всей системе, то есть начинать с точки монтирования "/"

`-type f` - искать только файлы

`-name '*_workers.rb'` - в данном случае все, что заканчивается на "_workers.rb"